# How to get absolute numbers of Array?

Tags: java

Can someone help me with this?

A series of 10 real numbers is given. Find the number closest to zero and the number furthest from zero. (that means you list the dessert of numbers in the program yourself, no loading!).
I tried with this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i,najdalji=0,najblizi=0;
int[] nums={-3,123,234,112,4,-9237,-382,92,121,99};
Arrays.sort(nums);
for( i=0 ; i<nums.length ; i++ )
{
    Math.abs(nums[i]);
    if(nums[i]>najdalji)
        nums[i] = najdalji;
    if(nums[i]<najblizi)
        nums[i] = najblizi;
}
System.out.println("Broj najblizi nuli je " + najblizi);
System.out.println("Broj najdalji nuli je " + najdalji);


}
```

najblizi is closest , najdalji is farthest
But i get 0 and 0

Comment: You never updated your values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.abs` won't edit the array "in place" - all it'll do is return the value. You need to do

```
nums[i] = Math.abs(nums[i]);
```

Also,

```
nums[i] = najdalji;
```

will assign `najdalji` to the array. I think you actually meant to do the reverse (assign `nums[i]` to `najdalji`). So:

```
najdalji = nums[i];
```

(The same change applies to `najblizi`).

Comment: Also `najblizi` has to be initialized with a value larger than zero, otherwise it will always stay 0.

Comment: And the algorithm above will return the absolute value of the closest number not the number itself.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution, which also replaces the static closest/farthest to zero by closest/farthest to a given bias. Hope it helps.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Demo {

    /**
     * Returns the number within an int array, which is closest to the given bias.
     *
     * @param numbers numbers to search within
     * @param bias the bias to use
     * @return number out of numbers, which is closest to bias
     */
    public static int getClosestToBias(int[] numbers, int bias) {
        int retval = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int num : numbers) {
            int diff = absDiff(num, bias);
            if (diff < min) {
                min = diff;
                retval = num;
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number within an int array, which is farthest away from the given bias.
     *
     * @param numbers numbers to search within
     * @param bias the bias to use
     * @return number out of numbers, which is farthest away from bias
     */
    public static int getFarthestFromBias(int[] numbers, int bias) {
        int retval = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int num : numbers) {
            int diff = absDiff(num, bias);
            if (diff > max) {
                max = diff;
                retval = num;
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the absolute difference between two ints.
     *
     * @param a first number
     * @param b second number
     * @return the absolute difference between the two numbers
     */
    public static int absDiff(int a, int b) {
        return Math.max(a, b) - Math.min(a, b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int[] nums = { -3, 123, 234, 112, 4, -9237, -382, 92, 121, 99 };

        System.out.println("Closest to zero: " + getClosestToBias(nums, 0));
        System.out.println("Farthest from zero: " + getFarthestFromBias(nums, 0));

        // Just a little performance test
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = -100_000; i <= 100_000; i++) {
            getClosestToBias(nums, i);
            getFarthestFromBias(nums, i);
        }
        long diff = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("Duration: " + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(diff) + " ms");
    }
}
```